# Runtime error 438 in Word for OS X

Tags: macos, ms-word

I have a Word document with macros that I am trying to open in Word 2011 for OS X.
I am getting the error "Runtime 438".  I select to debug the macro and Word highlights the following code that is NOT in my macro:

```
private Sub Document_Open()
  ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Today").Item(1).Range.Text = Form(Date, "m/d/yyy")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like error "438" is "Object doesn't support this property or method". (cf. http://www.excelbanter.com/showthread.php?t=312817)

I guess this file works fine on Windows, but you're trying to perform an operation that the  limited Mac implementation of VBasic doesn't implement.